# Counting various data in various ways

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Hi what i am trying to do is get the order history from amazon using the MWS api and then show the data by day as a summery, here is the code i currently have and what it outputs.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$dates = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo "<head><link href='../../../public/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/></head>";
//echo  "<div class='col-md-12'><div class='col-md-2'>Date</div><div class='col-md-2'>Sales</div><div class='col-md-2'>Amount Shipped</div><div class='col-md-2'>Order Total</div><div class='col-md-2'></div><div class='col-md-2'></div></div>";
foreach ($dates as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($response->getListOrdersResult()->Orders as $order) {
        if (strpos($order->PurchaseDate, $value) !== false) {
            if(substr($order->PurchaseDate, 0, -10) == "$value" ) {
                $array[] = $order->BuyerName;
            }
        echo  "<div class='col-md-12'><div class='col-md-2'>$order->BuyerName</div><div class='col-md-2'>$order->OrderStatus</div><div class='col-md-2'>".$order->OrderTotal->Amount."</div><div class='col-md-2'>".$order->NumberOfItemsShipped."</div><div class='col-md-2'>".substr($order->PurchaseDate, 0, -10)."</div></div>";
        }
    }
}
```

So this code currently uses the returned data from the MWS api, and then puts the data in to columns grouped together by there sale date, here is what that looks like.

```
 name    status  amount  date

Somebody Shipped 25.981 2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 7.971 2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 14.371 2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 25.981 2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 25.981 2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 29.9712015-01-13
------------------------------------------------------------------2015-01-13
Somebody Shipped 25.981 2015-01-12
Somebody Shipped 35.152 2015-01-12
------------------------------------------------------------------2015-01-12
```

What i want it to do is count how many records there are for a date, for example there are 6 for the 13th  and two for the 12th then i would like the add all the amounts up so here is what i would like the correct version of this to output using the same data

```
 Date       Sales    Amount
```

### 2015-1-13    6       130.25

```
2015-01-12   2        60
```

Any help in achieving this would be much appropriated, i don't think i have left any key information out as all that data is inside the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the values into an array. Check is the date in the loop is equal as the previous date. If not, set the prev date to the current date, then create an array key, and add an array with the current amount, and set the counter to 1, if yes, then incrase the coutner, and add the amount to the previous amount. Of course, `$response->getListOrdersResult()->Orders` should be ordered by date.

```
$oldDate = 0;
$amounts = array();
foreach ($response->getListOrdersResult()->Orders as $order) {
    if (strpos($order->PurchaseDate, $value) !== false) {
        if (substr($order->PurchaseDate, 0, -10) == "$value") {
            $array[] = $order->BuyerName;
        }
        $date = substr($order->PurchaseDate, 0, -10);
        if ($date !== $oldDate) {
            $oldDate = $date;
            $amounts[$date] = array(
                'amount' => $order->OrderTotal->Amount,
                'cnt' => 1
            );
        } else {
            $amounts[$date]['cnt'] ++;
            $amounts[$date]['amount'] += $order->OrderTotal->Amount;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($amounts);
```